# how to know which method is calling other method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jscript

consider i have many methods in jscript.. 
method1()

method2()

method3()

Now method1() and method2() are independent. where method3() is called by both the methods. I want to know from which method method3() is getting called. either method1() or method2()

Comment: @luiges90 hmmm yea it looks a duplicate. But i couldnot find it and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is simple code

```
function method1(){
  method3('method1');
}

function method2(){
  method3('method2');
}

function method3(method){
  alert(method);
}
```

[Reference](http://jsbin.com/atAsUkA/2)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
function method3() {
    alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```

Comment: it displays method body also in alert like caller is function met1() {
    method3();
}

Comment: it says package arguments.callee doesnot exist

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code which logs the Caller method name :

```
function method1(){
  method3();
}

function method2(){
  method3();
}

function method3(){
    console.log(method3.caller.name);
}
method1(); // method1
method2(); // method2
```